# AppleScript: How do I activate an app when it is in fullscreen mode?

Tags: applescript, focus

I have tried `tell application Emacs to activate` but it doesn't work when emacs is in fullscreen mode and focuses desktop instead (with the toolbar set on emacs).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If your talking about [Emacs For Mac OS X](https://emacsformacosx.com), then there should be a **Dock Tile** of the **Emacs.app** showing on the **Dock**, and you can set focus to the fullscreen occurrence, assuming there is only one occurrence of the **Emacs.app** running, with the following **AppleScript** *code*:

```
if application "Emacs" is running then
    tell application "System Events" to click UI element "Emacs" of list 1 of application process "Dock"
end if
```

By clicking the **Dock Tile**, it takes you to the fullscreen occurrence where you can then run other *code* in your *script* to interact with **Emacs**. Obviously if **Emacs** is not in fullscreen view, this will bring the **Emacs** window forward the same as `tell application "Emacs" to activate` does.

Comment: I am using this in a script that is run by emacsclient; How do I add it to the list of apps allowed to control my computer? (Otherwise it can't use "System Events")